# Can't use maven command-line tool

Tags: java, maven, terminal, java-home

Here is the message I get when I try to use maven in the terminal:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

This is the definition of the JAVA_HOME environment variable:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME                                                                                1 ✘ 
/usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime/bin/java

java --version                                                                                   ✔ 
openjdk 19.0.2 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the `java` executable, not the directory containing the Java installation, as it should be

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really mistyped the wrong path in JAVA_HOME